# Mouse and keyboard freezes in lightdm

Tags: boot, keyboard, mouse, freeze, lightdm

After last system update (week ago) I noticed that my mouse and keyboard freezes after boot-up, in the lightdm login screen for 1-2 minutes, so I can't move pointer or type my password.

Although, my personalized wallpaper appears, cursor in *Password* field blinks and notification about internet connection appears, so it's not the entire screen freeze.

After these 1-2 minutes, mouse and keyboard start working until next boot *(I didn't noticed freeze after logout to lightdm login screen)*.

It's pretty annoying, so I will grateful for help.

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.10 stable** release and **GRUB** as bootloader. If you'll need more information about my software or hardware, ask.

Oh, and I've got wired keyboard and mouse, not wireless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. All I've got to do was upgrading software with command:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now mouse and keyboard are working fine.